# Please recommend a complete guide/book on MVVM for silverlight

Tags: mvvm

Although there are many MVVM for silverlight demo app/article online, but all of them are very simple and not cover mvvm with depth and extension for LOB app. 
I am looking for a complete MVVM book/demo in depth related to such as WCF Ria Services, Command, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Advanced MVVM](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/) by Josh Smith.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced MVVM is a good book about basic MVVM concepts, but it does not address the issues for LOB apps.  Keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners : Take a look at the following article on [MVVM basics](http://programmingwpf.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/step-by-step-guide-to-mvvm/)